# ruby array group by multiple element values

Tags: arrays, ruby, group-by

I tried searching for an answer but nothing I found has worked...

I have an array that looks like this... `[["10", "20", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"]]` and I'd like to group them by both the first and second elements.

Result `[[["10", "20", "1", 1]], [["10", "30", "1", 2], ["10", "30", "1"]]]`

From what I found I've tried these...

`list.group_by{|w| w[3]}.values do |v1| v1.group_by{|l| l[4]} end`

`list.group_by{|w| w; [w[3], w[4]]}.map{|k, v| [k.first, k.last, v.length]}`

This works but only takes one of the elements into account when grouping...

`sub_group=list.group_by{|w| [w[3], w[4]]}.values`

`sub_group.each{|group| group[0] << group.length}`

Comment: Why there's no `2` in the second array from the second array in your result example?

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia I just need the length result to be in the first subarray... bu t the length is optional, I use this `sub_group.each{|group| group[0] << group.length}` to get the length of each nested array.

Comment: You need to edit to better state the question (forgetting, for now, what you've tried). Specifically, you need to state the rules that produce your stated "Result" for the example you have given. I can't figure it out and I'm probably not alone, especially because no answers have appeared nearly one hour after you posted the question. A more elaborate example and/or a second example would be helpful.

Comment: Tip: Use `%w[ 10 20 1 ]` as an alternative to the syntax-heavy `[ "10", "20", "1" ]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added the bit of code that adds the length to the result array I posted, hopefully it adds clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the array to get a count of elements, then map the values by checking their index, when it's 0 then you add the total elements;

```
[["10", "20", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"]]
  .group_by(&:itself)
  .values
  .map do |values|
    values.map.with_index do |value, i|
      next value + [values.length] if i.zero?

      value
    end
  end
# [[["10", "20", "1", 1]], [["10", "30", "1", 2], ["10", "30", "1"]]]
```

Comment: You could just do `group_by(...).values.map` and skip the `transform_values(...).values` part.

Comment: beautiful beautiful

Answer (score 1):

With [`Enumerable#tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) and [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```rb
[["10", "20", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"]]
  .tally
  .each_with_object([]) do |(item, count), new_ary|
    new_item = item.dup
    new_item << count
    
    new_ary << [new_item]
    (count - 1).times { new_ary.last << item }
  end

# => [[["10", "20", "1", 1]], [["10", "30", "1", 2], ["10", "30", "1"]]]
```

You can also use [`Array#flatten!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21) instead first two lines inside `each_with_object`. In this case in `times` you need `item[..-2]`

```
[["10", "20", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"], ["10", "30", "1"]]
  .tally
  .each_with_object([]) do |item, new_ary|
    item.flatten!
    
    new_ary << [item]
    (item.last - 1).times { new_ary.last << item[..-2] }
  end

# => [[["10", "20", "1", 1]], [["10", "30", "1", 2], ["10", "30", "1"]]]
```